# Change VSCode setting without updating settings.json (i.e. just for session)

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the most part I don't want the Activity view visible, so my `settings.json` file has `"workbench.activityBar.visible": false`. Occasionally I want to browse through a menu so I'll toggle its visibility on. This updates my `settings.json`, which is kind of annoying since I only want it temporarily.

Is there a way to change a setting in the current "session", but then have it back to the desired setting when VSCode restarts?

I'm aware of the [user/workspace/folder precedence](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-precedence), but in my case I'd prefer that none of the files are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` and search for `activity bar`. You will see a setting named `View: Toggle Activity Bar Visibility`, click on the pencil on the side to edit it and assign a keybind to it. After setting your desired key combination, whenever you press that you will toggle the visibility of the activity bar. This **still changes** your settings.json but you can just press your keybind again to switch it back very quickly. Hope that could fix your issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately I was hoping for a way to change this w/o updating settings.json.